# how can spring cloud dataflow app use private Docker repository?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a spring cloud dataflow server deployed on kubernetes cluster(not a local scdf server run from jar). Since it requires Docker images to register the apps, but my private docker repository would need credentials to pass the authentication.
Does anyone know on which configuration item/file shall I put my private docker repository credentials?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There's no special handling required from SCDF perspective.

As far as the Kubernetes cluster and from within the backing VMs, if the Docker Deamon is logged into the private registry, at the event of app-resolution, SCDF will run it on the same Docker Deamon, so everything should work automatically.

In other words, it is a setup configuration between the Kubernetes cluster and private registry - nothing specific to SCDF.

For example, [PKS and Harbor](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/using-vmware-s-harbor-with-pks-and-why-kubernetes-needs-a-container-registry) integration comes out of the box with this setup.

**EDIT**

If the above setup didn't work, there's the option to create `Secret` in Kubernetes, which can be used to generate a secret for the private registry - see docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-in-the-cluster-that-holds-your-authorization-token).

Once you've that configured, you can then pass to SCDF via `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.imagePullSecret` property. Going by the above example in the Kubernetes docs, the value for this property would be `regcred`.

Comment: Thanks Sabby, but I tried and none works so far. I am thinking about how to make the deployment(actual stream pod) that SCDF made in kubernetes to have "imagePullSecrets" section in the {deployment}.yaml. I am using a workaround that is creating a private docker repository without credentials so I don't have to put secrets in there.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have created [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes#269](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/269) to document the recommended approach. Feel free to share what you did as a workaround in the comment.